# Laravel hasManyDeep issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have implemented this relationship where a warehouse belongsToMany products that has Many sales.

My models be like

warehouse.php

```
public function products () {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('quantity');
}
```

product.php

```
public function sales () {
    return $this->hasMany(Sale::class);
}
```

I want to access sales directly from my Warehouse model to sum a column in the sales table.

I have used staudenmeir's [GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) package and added a `sales` method in my Warehouse model.

```
public function sales () {
    return $this->hasManyDeep(Sale::class, ['product_warehouse', Product::class]);
}
```

What I want to do is basically to sum total column of sales table so I've added a `withSum()` method in my WarehouseController like this

```
return Warehouse::query()
        ->withSum('sales', 'total')
        ->get();
```

Result

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "warehouse": "Algeria",
      "sales_sum_total": "1000"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "warehouse": "India",
      "sales_sum_total": "1000"
   }
]
```

The issue here is when I add a new sale to the India warehouse it returns the same values for all warehouses. I think that I'm not using the `hasManyDeep()` method the right way or perhaps it doesn't work for my use case. Is there anything I can do to get this to work?

Edit:
My database structure

```
    Schema::create('warehouses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('warehouse');
    });

    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->decimal('price');
    });

    Schema::create('product_warehouse', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('warehouse_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->integer('quantity')->default(0);
    });

    Schema::create('sales', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('warehouse_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->decimal('total');
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you have `warehouse_id` in `sales` table you can deal with it as a simple `hasMany` relation and call the `sum` on it,
I tested your case and got the right results, I just added sales relation on warehouse model:

```
public function sales()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sale::class);
}
```

And I just did:

```
return Warehouse::withSum('sales', 'total')->get();
```

Comment: This won't work in my case since I have many to many relationship between Warehouse and Product models

Comment: Down voting, not suitable for this situation

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the answer

Comment: @YasserSebai I didn't vote down and I wouldn't. I do appreciate his answer even if it doesn't work for me

Comment: Ok, appreciate your appreciation, thanks for making stack overflow a better community

Comment: @Othmane would you please share your database structure?

Comment: @RatebHabbab Did it. I appreciate your time!

Comment: @Othmane Would you check it now, Did it solve your problem?

Comment: @RatebHabbab that worked like a charm. Answer accepted!